# Rails link_to with method delete performs get request with turbolinks enabled

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

`link_to with :method => :delete` is performing a **GET** request when Turbolinks are enabled. As soon as I disable Turbolinks it works again. I've exhausted my research into possible solutions including:

1) Made sure the helper is producing the correct HTML

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/admin/organizations/1">Delete</a>
```

2) Tried it with Turbolinks enabled and `data-no-turbolinks` on the link

3) Ensured jquery and jquery-ujs are both being loaded

```
<script src="/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ujs/src/rails.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

4) Tried it with and without `jquery.turbolinks`

5) Ensured there are no javascript errors in the console

6) Made sure js file is loaded in the head with `data-turbolinks-track` (It's the only javascript include)

```
javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

7) Checked routes and request logs (**GET** is being performed instead of **DELETE**)

```
21:56:40 web.1  | Started GET "/admin/organizations/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-17 21:56:40 -0500
```

8) Ensured `$(document)` is bound to `'page:change'`

I do not want to use `button_to` (which does work). Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your `application.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a call to e.stopPropagation() on a click handler in a js file. I have no idea why that was causing the problem, I have other calls to stopPropagation and this was on a different portion of the page (header) than where the delete link was being called (main body). So solved but still confused.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was fixed by replacing `//= require jquery_ujs` with `//= require rails-ujs` in **application.js**

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56281048/2009652