# Ruby on Rails: link_to vs button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am having trouble implementing the method link_to. My program uses a link to call a controller method which performs some logic and renders a partial. The issue is I cant get the link to call the controller method. I have tried calling the same controller method with button_to and it seems to work. Looking at the API of both ActionView helper methods button_to and link_to it seems like the parameters should be the same. However, the following two lines of code do two different things.

_product.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'view individual', products_view_individual_product_page_path(product_id: product.id)%>
<%= button_to 'view individual', products_view_individual_product_page_path(product_id: product.id)%>
```

The link_to call will cause an error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error stating "Couldn't find Product with 'id'=view_individual_product_page" and the passed parameters are {"product_id"=>"261", "id"=>"view_individual_product_page"}, im not sure why it is trying to pass the path of my controller method as the id. However the button_to line of code works just fine, and I am in the specified controller method. Here is the route entry in my routes.rb file...

routes.rb

```rb
post 'products/view_individual_product_page'
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong here, I cant find much information online about why the path is being passed as an ID in link_to but not button_to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `method: :post` as an option for link_to.

```
link_to 'view individual', products_view_individual_product_page_path(product_id: product.id), method: :post
```

"A" tags always does GET requests and you are expecting a POST request. Note that you need Rails Unobtrusive Javascript for links to trigger a POST request with Rails doing some magic behind the scenes (check your javascript application.js, you should have a `require rails-ujs`).

Usually, if you need to do a POST request it's okey to have a `button_to` since it actually renders a FORM tag with a button to do a proper POST request without the need of Rails UJS.

Check the doc for both:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: I see, I tried adding the method: :post and the link worked. did not know they used different http methods. Thank you for the answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is that `link_to` by default use a `GET` method, where `button_to` use `POST`. So if you want a different method, specify it

```
<%= link_to 'view individual', products_view_individual_product_page_path(product_id: product.id), method: :post %>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for the answer and explanation!

Comment: Hey, don't worry, my pleasure :)